# purchase individual items and subscriptions in the same PayPal REST API transaction

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I've looked for help on this extensively, and it seems that there is always some confusion on the part of the person answering as to what is trying to be accomplished.

I have several items to purchase. Some are things (t-shirts, books, event tickets, etc.) and some are monthly subscriptions for an ongoing service.

What would the process be to process a purchase that contains a thing and a subscription.

I have been able to work with the REST API to successfully process a simple item purchase, and also to create a billing plan and successfully purchase a subscription (billing agreement) to that plan. What I cannot figure out is how to accomplish both at the same time, with only one trip to PayPal for payment authorization.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Note, I am effectively working with the CURL based transactions as there is no Lasso based SDK available.